# 'bash: yo: command not found' on osx

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, yeoman

I know this has been asked before but I'm unable to find a solution. I'm trying to run the `yo` command from the terminal and I keep getting the `yo: command not found` error.

From the root directory I ran `npm install -g yo` and everything installed correctly. It installed to:

`/Users/jamie/npm/lib/node_modules/yo`

I have `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files.

`.bash_profile` contains the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

And the `.bashrc` file contains:

```
source dnvm.sh
```

Thank you. I appreciate it.

***edit***

There is a `yo` directory inside of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. But when I run `/usr/local/lib/node_modules yo` it says it is a directory, however none of the yo generators run.

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules yo aspnet` simply returns:

`-bash: /usr/local/lib/node_modules: is a directory`

Comment: `lib/node_modules/yo` is a directory, not a binary file; it's not, and doesn't define, a command you can run -- directories can define commands on OS X (specifically), but Node modules follow more general UNIX conventions, which do nothing of the sort. The pertinent questions are where `.../bin/yo` is, and what your PATH contains.

Comment: ...I'd suggest running `find "$HOME" -type f -name yo`.

Comment: on my system, when i install `yo` globally, the output shows this: `/usr/local/bin/yo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js` meaning it is supposed to be symlinked when you run `npm`. is that happening?

Comment: I have this path: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js`

Comment: When I run `find "$HOME" -type f -name yo` nothing is returned.

Comment: `find /usr/local -name yo`, then?

Comment: 'find /usr/local -name yo' returns `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo`

Comment: Err, I forgot the `-type f`; directories aren't of any use.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the `yo` wrapper installed by `npm`, then you can run:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js aspnet
```

...or, if that lacks a working shebang:

```
node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js aspnet
```

However, your best bet is to find the `yo` wrapper, and add the directory it's in to your PATH.

---

Alternately, you can do that yourself (though it makes you responsible for uninstallation/cleanup later):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js /usr/local/bin/yo
```

Comment: I ran `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js /usr/local/bin/yo ` and then tried `yo aspnet` and I still got no such file or directory.

Comment: @reknirt you shouldn't have to create your own symlink or implement a workaround. something is wrong with your configuration

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there anyway to wipe my config and start over?

Comment: Set your PATH to contain `/usr/local/bin`.